# Undefined variable notice (PHP)

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I have a member.php page which contains this piece of code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['teacherusername'])) 
    {
        $username = $_SESSION['teacherusername'];
    }
?>
```

Now in the teacherlogin.php I use "include" to include the code from the member.php page. The problem I have is that if I open up the teacherlogin.php page, it gives me an undefined variable error stating: 
`Notice: Undefined variable: username in ... on line 25`

Why is it stating it is undefined because I have defined it in the member.php page?

Below is the code in the teacherlogin.php:

```
<?php
  // PHP code
  session_start(); 

    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

// connect to the database
include('connect.php');
include('member.php');

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
  }

  // required variables (make them explciit no need for foreach loop)
  $teacherusername = (isset($_POST['teacherusername'])) ? $_POST['teacherusername'] : '';
  $teacherpassword = (isset($_POST['teacherpassword'])) ? $_POST['teacherpassword'] : '';
  $loggedIn = false;
  $active = true;

  if ($username){
      echo "You are already Logged In: <b>{$_SESSION['teacherforename']} {$_SESSION['teachersurname']}</b> | <a href='./teacherlogout.php'>Logout</a>";
  }
  else{

echo "Please Login";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$username` is only set by your member.php when the user is logged in. Try using `if(isset($username))` instead of `if($username)` in your teacherlogin.php.

Answer (score 1):

It is defined only into the if block.

```
$username = "";
if (isset($_SESSION['teacherusername'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['teacherusername'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$username` is not defined or used anywhere.

Do the same as on the member.php at the top op the teacherlogin.php

> if (isset($_SESSION['teacherusername'])) {
>
> ```
>   $username = $_SESSION['teacherusername']; 
> }
> ```

Comment: Maybe you should read the whole post first before commenting...

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = null; // ad this line to member.php 
if (isset($_SESSION['teacherusername'])) {
   $username = $_SESSION['teacherusername'];
```